# Horizontal Scrolling, fit to Content Width

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a page with the following structure:

`div.wrapper` > `div.content` > `div.item` + `div.item`

The wrapper has a width of 320px, whereas the two `div.item` come out to around 600px. I need those two to be displayed inline (right now they are `display: inline-block;`, and have the wrapper's contents scroll horizontally. When I set the `div.content` width to `auto`, it takes the width of the wrapper (320px). Setting the width to 200% obviously gets the horizontal scrolling to work, but how do I get `div.content` to take on the width of its contents to allow for horizontal scrolling?

Note: The wrapper is set to a fixed width and height and has `overflow-y: hidden` and `overflow-x: scroll` set, because I do *not* want vertical scrolling-- only horizontal.

JSFiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kh5k7/

As you can see, the red divs will vertically stack. Changing the `.content` width to 200% (or some value) will cause horizontal scrolling to occur properly. I want this done automatically though, because I have no clue how many elements are going to be in the `.content` div before hand.

Comment: can you post your html+css in jsfiddle?

Comment: Done. http://jsfiddle.net/kh5k7/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`white-space:nowrap;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-word-spacing) on `.content`

```
.content{
   width: auto;
   white-space:nowrap; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kh5k7/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can have something like this:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.content {
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```